# In angularjs 1.0.8 not works PUT rest service

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, angularjs, express

I have angularjs application which have CRUD Rest service. Create, Read and Delete methods works well, but PUT not works.
I found on Stackoverflow and there are the same problems with accepted answers e.g.:

[Angular JS: Full example of GET/POST/DELETE/PUT client for a REST/CRUD backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376890/angular-js-full-example-of-get-post-delete-put-client-for-a-rest-crud-backend)

[AngularJS - PUT method not working (404 error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650163/angularjs-put-method-not-working-404-error)

So I do it like in this answers but my update (by PUT method) not works (Status code: 404 'Cannot PUT /api/adverts').
Maybe folks notice something in my code. One important thing is that I use **angular 1.0.8**

services.js (angularjs):

```
var motoAdsServices = angular.module('motoAdsServices', ['ngResource']);

motoAdsServices.factory('Advert', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/adverts/:advertId', {}, {
       update: {method:'PUT', params: {advertId: '@advertId'}}
    });
  }]);
```

editAdvert.html

```
  <label class="control-label">Brand</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select name="brand" ng-model="editAdvert.brand" required ng-options="b.name for b in brands">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <label class="control-label">Model</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select name="model" ng-model="editAdvert.model" required ng-options="m.name for m in editAdvert.brand.models">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

controllers.js (angular.js - I removed no significant code):

```
$scope.updateAdvert = function() {
  var editAdvert = {
    _id: $scope.editAdvert._id,
    brandName: $scope.editAdvert.brand.name,
    modelName: $scope.editAdvert.model.name,
    year: $scope.editAdvert.year,
    price: $scope.editAdvert.price,
    imageUrl: $scope.editAdvert.imageUrl,
    countryName: $scope.editAdvert.country.name,
    regionName: $scope.editAdvert.region.name
  };

  // !!! I TRY THIS TO FIX !!!
  $scope.advertId = $scope.editAdvert._id;

  // !!! THIS NOT WORKS STILL !!!
  Advert.update(editAdvert, function() {
    previousAdvert = angular.copy($scope.editAdvert);
    alert('Advert updated');
  });
};
```

server.js (nodejs):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var adverts = require('./routes/adverts');

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));  /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/api/adverts', adverts.findAll);
app.get('/api/adverts/:id', adverts.findById);
app.post('/api/adverts', adverts.add);
app.put('/api/adverts/:id', adverts.update);
app.delete('/api/adverts/:id', adverts.remove);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

In response I get 404 and 'Cannot PUT /api/adverts'.
I'm almost convinced that it is the problem of lack '_id' at the end of URL.
See the picture:
[image]

Please look at my code and give some suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some inconsistencies here. Firstly, the `update` should be the instance method. So the call should be like this: `$scope.editAdvert.$update(...` instead of  `Advert.update($scope.editAdvert...`

Another thing here is the difference in the argument names. The resource is instructed, that the *id* of the resource should be `advertId`, while, as the picture shows, the object has id named `_id`

And finally, you are setting `$scope.advertId = $scope.editAdvert._id;` ... as you say to fix it. The problem is, that it is not related to the object `$scope.editAdvert` ... it just another object of the $scope. The Resource is not aware of it.

See more details about the [ngResource here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: Thanks! 1. `update` isn't the instance method because `var editAdvert` (it has `brandName` simple string) which I put to `Advert.update` is other than `$scope.editAdvert` (i has `brand` complex object). I use $scope.Advert in editAdvert.html to work with select (see the code - I updated to show you). 2. It's perfect suggestion I change my code to `update: {method:'PUT', params: {advertId: '@_id'}}` and it WORKS! 3. I remove my fix. If you can look at my updated code `controllers.js` and `editAdvert.html` and check now inconsistencies.

Comment: Of course the FIX line is removed and I changed in services.js `update: {method:'PUT', params: {advertId: '@_id'}}`

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy Angular