# $update PUT method in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs, angular-ui-router

I couldn't find any examples of using an $update PUT method in Angular when using ui-router instead of ngRoute for routing. Is an $update PUT method possible when using ui-router?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by a put method in the routes? is that in the `resolve` option or...? are you sure you mean `ui-router` and `ngRoute` ? because routing in angular doesnt have much to do with regards to HTTP. The only use (outside of the resolve block) is probably to retrieve templates specified with `templateUrl` and that will be (and should be) a GET request. Perhaps you mean't the angular-resource module ($resource)?

Comment: In this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650163/angularjs-put-method-not-working-404-error they use $routeParams. $scope.action.$update({actionid: $routeParams.actionid})
I'd like to do something like this but with ui-router which uses $stateParams instead of $routeParams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$update` method in the example you linked in the question comments has nothing to do with `$routeParams` or `$stateParams`. Those (in most cases) just refer the parameters that are present within the url.

As an example, if you declared a url in your config as: `/#/foo/:id/bar` and you visited the url: `/#/foo/5/bar?hello=world&verified=1` then `$routeParams` and `$stateParams` would be an object that looks like:

```
{id: 5, hello: "world", verified: "1"}
```

**Note:** In the case of $stateParams, I think the url in the config might need to be declared as: `/foo/:id/bar?hello&verified`

As for the `$update` method and `PUT` requests, these are related to the angular-resource module. You'll notice from the example you cited that a service (factory) was declared that makes use of the `$resource` service. if you take a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) specifically under the **Returns** section you'll see that the `$resource` service will return:

> A resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource actions optionally extended with custom actions. The default set contains these actions:

```
{'get':    {method:'GET'},
 'save':   {method:'POST'},
 'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
 'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
 'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

It further states:

> The actions save, remove and delete are available on it as methods with the $ prefix.

So `$save`, `$remove`, `$delete` are avaiable but no $update. This is why the service in the example has the line:

```
...
'update': { method: 'PUT'},
...
```

It's meant to extend these default set of actions so that `$update` will be available as a method on the objects and it will use the HTTP PUT method instead of GET/POST/DELETE like the others.

I sugggest you do further reading on [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams), [$stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) and [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) but hopefully the distinction between them is clear.