# why must set update: { method: 'PUT' } in $resource angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I have sample code in meanjs, i don't understand why they must set third paprameter

```
  update: {
    method: 'PUT'
  }
```

This is full code:

```js
'use strict';

//Articles service used for communicating with the articles REST endpoints
angular.module('articles').factory('Articles', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/articles/:articleId', {
      articleId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) specifically under the **Returns** section you'll see that the `$resource` service will return:

> A resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource actions optionally extended with custom actions. The default set contains these actions:

```
{'get':    {method:'GET'},
 'save':   {method:'POST'},
 'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
 'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
 'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

It further states:

> The actions save, remove and delete are available on it as methods with the $ prefix.

So `$save`, `$remove`, `$delete` are avaiable but no $update. This is why the service in the example has the line:

```
...
'update': { method: 'PUT'},
...
```

It's meant to extend these default set of actions so that `$update` will be available as a method on the objects and it will use the HTTP PUT method instead of GET/POST/DELETE like the others.

*Note: the above answer was extracted from a [previous question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31296465/2556428) but I've isolated the part you should focus on here*

Comment: You could also use **PATCH** instead of **PUT** if you are doing partial updates to the object to save on bandwidth. [RFC 5789](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789)

Comment: Thank you very much, it very usefull to me :)